# UK new visa application - I need to submit my old passport with expired visa, but don't have my old passport

Tags: visas, uk

I have my current passport and the passport before that. I need to show 10 year travel history. I have listed all of my travel history but my 2 passports that I'm submitting are from 2011 and 2016 onwards. My passport prior to this to cover me from 2009-2011 is not with me and I will not be able to get it on time for my biometrics appointment.

Is it actually necessary when I already have 2 passports, and the passport prior to that was of me when I was a minor (under 16)?

If it is necessary - is it acceptable to provide pictures/copies for now, then provide the physical copy later on once I can have it mailed to me?

Answer (score 1):

You have copies? This is enough. They will ask you eventually the original passport (but not all people keep it, and often authorities destroyed it, when giving you the new one).

Travel history is one point in your favour (especially if you where minor in the initial 10 year period: you have not responsibilities of being in enemy countries).

If you have long travel history after 2011, this is good. If you traveled as adult: better, and also better: with your own funds.

With you as minor, the travel history is less important. It shows up that you are used to travel, and possibly that your parents were honest (and with funds), which could help you to asses your link to your home country (possibly your parents could assist you financially), but it is difficult to asses your actual intention from such history.

So: copies should be OK. If you are at risk not to get the visa (because of other points), original passport could help, but I think not so much. Travel history is not the most important point. Check to have good documentation on the other items.

Comment: Note: I really mean "enemy countries". By going in foreign countries we do not have problems, but if you travel to Syria, Afghanistan, etc. you may have extra screening (depending of country). Or Israel with Iran stamps or the contrary, or a lot more cases, often listed in visa application (adding special requirements).

Comment: Entering Israel with Iran stamps is likely a problem, but the reverse isn't a problem because you can't encounter that situation.  Israel doesn't stamp your passport (you get a little slip of paper instead of a stamp, exactly so that after you leave there's no evidence of your visit left in your passport)

Comment: @BenVoigt: for standard tourism entry, when you do not requires visa. And some people may have them from a previous travel. And the security stickers on the cover of passport, better to remove it. [And when you enter/exit from road, Egypt and Jordan put a visa with the point of entry].